# centralized vs. federated convergence

Tags: tensorflow-federated

So I've got some data from 700-some smart meters. Data from each meter includes electricity usage taken in intervals of 15 mins, outside temperature, humidity, if it's a national holiday...
The goal is to predict combined electricity usage of the users on the grid.
When I combine the data by summing all the electricity and train my model (normalization, some batching, 3 lstm layers with 512 nodes, some dropout, relu activation, adam optimizer, absolute loss, default lr) I get good results which I am happy with.
But when I do it in federated, with each user training on his private data, using the same model I did (server lr = 1.0, because its less confusing i think) i get really bad results. 
Unsystematically I messed around with batch size, switching adam for SGD, changing learning rates, upping the epochs, changing the number of users calculating gradients in each round. Nothing seemed to work.

Should i just up the epochs in some order of magnitude? Do i have any theoretical assurance that there exists a set of parameters under which the same model that converged on the sum of data should should converge in federated?
It's more of a soft question, but i may post the code or the results if needed.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that strikes me in the question is the mention of normalization. In TFF's [default federated averaging implementation](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/build_federated_averaging_process?version=nightly), [only trainable variables are averaged](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/main/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/federated_averaging.py#L128) across clients.

Keras' `BatchNorm` implementation uses non-trainable variables to track mean and standard deviation of the parameters across batches, so there is bad composition here. There has been success using TFF's [GroupNorm](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/1868b9b1af37efd377d0f73ce143df431cfde82e/tensorflow_federated/python/simulation/models/group_norm.py#L22) implementation, however, as a drop-in replacement. Are you using BatchNorm? If so, I might recommend trying to simply swap for GroupNorm.

Comment: Hi @Keith , is there other well known problems with using batch normalization other than need to aggregate non-trainable variables. As I explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69525476/federated-averaging-fedavg-with-resnet-18-that-has-batch-normalization-makes-t) I aggregated both trainable and non-trainable variables but for some reason had problems with first round alone. I would appreciate your insight